# iTunes is trying to upgrade to iOS 4.3.5 instead of iOS 5

Tags: ipad, ios

Currently I'm running iOS 4.3.3 on my iPad.

I was expecting to ugrade to iOS 5 directly.but iTunes is trying to upgrade to iOS 4.3.5.

Do I need to first upgrade to 4.3.5 and then to iOS 5? Is there any way to upgrade to iOS 5 directly?

I can, however, download the ipsw. But anyway I would like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Connected my iPad, started iTunes, and was offered iOS 4.3.5 (and this was just last week!). I had iTunes up to date and everything.

I canceled the upgrade, closed and reopened iTunes, and it then decided to offer to upgrade to 5.0.

I think it will resolve itself. Try restarting.

Answer (score 1):

What version of iTunes are you using?

To upgrade to iOS 5 you need the latest iTunes 10.5, since the earlier versions do not recognize the iOS 5 IPSW and cannot sync with iOS 5. They will also not detect the iOS 5 upgrade on the iTunes server.

Comment: I just upgraded to iTunes 10.5 (the latest). It's asking for 4.3.5 anyway

Comment: Very strange. I have not yet had an issue trying to do the upgrade from an older version. I would suggest you then download either the IPSW directly or do the upgrade to 4.3.5.